# How to add a url for data in Map box GL JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a rails app that uses Mapbox js to add markers on a map. It works perfectly with Mapbox JS. However, I cannot figure out how to get it to work with Mapbox GL JS.
Here is my controller index action:

```
def index
   @locations = Location.all

   @geojson = Array.new

   @locations.each do |location|
     @geojson << {
       type: 'Feature',
       geometry: {
         type: 'Point',
         coordinates: [location.longitude, location.latitude]
       },
       properties: {
         title: location.name,
         description: [location.elevation, location.locatable_type ],
         :'marker-color' => "#3ca0d3",
         :'marker-symbol' => "rocket",
         :'marker-size' => 'medium'
       }
     }
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @geojson }   
  end

end
```

In my view, I use this script to get the points on the map with Mapbox JS:

```
  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.mylongaccesskeygoeshere';

  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
  .setView([13.770391, -88.866245], 8);
  map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();    

  var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  .loadURL('/maps/index.json')
  .addTo(map);
```

My question is: How do I accomplish this with Mapbox GL JS? Here is the code I use to get the map on the page.

```
   mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.mylongaccesskeygoeshere';

   var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
   container: 'map', // container id
   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v9', //stylesheet location
   center: [-88.866245, 13.770391], // starting position
   zoom: 7.2 // starting zoom
   });
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to pass my url for the "data" like it says in the Mapbox GL JS documentation. For example, I tried

```
 mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.mylongaccesskeygoeshere';

  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v9', //stylesheet location
    center: [-88.866245, 13.770391], // starting position
    zoom: 7.2 // starting zoom
  });

  var url = '/maps/index.json';
    var source = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({
    data: url
  });

  map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('location', source);
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "location",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "location",
        "layout": {
          "icon-image": "rocket-15",
        }
    });
  });
```

I get this error in my console:

```
map.js:929 Error: Input data is not a valid GeoJSON
object.util.extend.onError        @ map.js:929
Evented.fire                      @ evented.js:90
util.extend._forwardSourceEvent   @ map.js:943
Evented.fire                      @ evented.js:90
util.inherit._forwardSourceEvent  @ style.js:680
Evented.fire                      @ evented.js:90
(anonymous function)              @ geojson_source.js:162
Actor.receive                     @ actor.js:31
```

When I go to maps/index.json the output of the json on the page looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -89.12312324,
        13.686886
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": "Random Location",
      "description": [
        "700.0",
        "Individual"
      ],
      "marker-color": "#3ca0d3",
      "marker-symbol": "rocket",
      "marker-size": "medium"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -88.231293812398,
        13.087893
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": "Some Place",
      "description": [
        "50.0",
        "Organization"
      ],
      "marker-color": "#3ca0d3",
      "marker-symbol": "rocket",
      "marker-size": "medium"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -89.224564,
        13.700985
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": "San Salvador",
      "description": [
        "550.0",
        "Individual"
      ],
      "marker-color": "#3ca0d3",
      "marker-symbol": "rocket",
      "marker-size": "medium"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -89.0,
        13.0
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": "Set Location Test",
      "description": [
        "100.0",
        "Individual"
      ],
      "marker-color": "#3ca0d3",
      "marker-symbol": "rocket",
      "marker-size": "medium"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

The issue is the json that my index action in my controller was generating. I used Mapbox's tool geojson hint https://www.mapbox.com/geojsonhint/ to debug my json. It turns out that:

The [ at the beginning and the ] at the end were problems

and I was missing

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
```

at the beginning.

So, instead of using the controller to generate the json. I used jbuilder.

changed my controller index action to look like this

```
def index
  @locations.Location.all
end
```

I created a view with extension .json.jbuilder and added

```
json.type "FeatureCollection"
json.features @locations do |location|
  json.type "Feature"
  json.geometry do 
    json.type "Point"
    json.coordinates [location.longitude.to_f,location.latitude.to_f]
  end
  json.properties do
    json.title location.name
  end
end
```

The resulting json is

```
 {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -89,
          13
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Random Location"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -88,
          13
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Some Place"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -89,
          13
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Fantacy Club Bar"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -89,
          13
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Set Location Test"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -89,
          14
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Some place else"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the to_f in the jbuilder code. That makes sure you get a float. The important thing is that the data is on the map.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an error message in your console that says "Input data is not a valid GeoJSON." Have you checked to see if your input data is valid GeoJSON?

GeoJSON is a subset of JSON. JSON does not support `//` comments.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. Sorry, I was using one of those browser extensions in chrome that adds that. the actual raw output doesn't have the // 20160527114134
or
// http://localhost:3000/maps/index.json